# Passing a parameter to threads in a loop

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I need to create 10 threads and print out the threadId with which thread printed.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI xprint(LPVOID Param)
{
DWORD tID = GetCurrentThreadId();
int count = *(int*)Param + 1;

fprintf(stderr, "Thread Number:%d ThreadID:%d\n", count, tID);

return 0;
}

int main ()
{
   DWORD ThreadID[10];
   HANDLE ThreadHandle[10];
   int i;

   for(i=0; i<10; i++){

    ThreadHandle[i] = CreateThread(
      NULL,
          0,
          xprint,
          &i,
          0,
          &ThreadID[i]);

    if (ThreadHandle[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't create thread!\n");
        return -1;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle[i],INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(ThreadHandle[i]);
    }
}
```

output:

```
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:4952
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:5284
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:5084
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:5656
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:5292
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:3072
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:5904
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:3620
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:6056
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:5676
```

I don't know where i did wrong.
my desired output should look something like this.

output:

```
Thread Number:10 ThreadID:4952
Thread Number:8 ThreadID:5284
Thread Number:3 ThreadID:5084
Thread Number:9 ThreadID:5656
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:5292
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:3072
Thread Number:5 ThreadID:5904
Thread Number:6 ThreadID:3620
Thread Number:4 ThreadID:6056
Thread Number:7 ThreadID:5676
```

The Thread Number should be *out of order.

*** After posting this question i ran the program a few more times
output:

```
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:4500
Thread Number:7 ThreadID:5740
Thread Number:7 ThreadID:3772
Thread Number:1 ThreadID:4732
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:4252
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:4264
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:5544
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:4116
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:5240
Thread Number:2 ThreadID:4804
```

it seems like the thread number is random. but in any case, no same number should appear twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not on a Windows machine, so I can't test this, but in a program I wrote I made an array of all the value, and did a pointer to the array element (`int numbers[100]; &number[i]`). The reason this worked was cause i was changing while the second thread was running.

Comment: I used your way to fix to problem. now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `&i`, why don't you just pass `i` and cast it back as needed? You're passing the same address to all your threads.

Comment: +1 Using a pointer to store this `int` parameter is a clever idea. I was thinking of `malloc`.

Comment: Because I forgot the pointers can store integers, that's why you get an upvote for this idea.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the at &i. in several demo codes the professor showed us, this is her "proper" way of passing it.

Comment: @user1766777 sometimes professors don't know s#!+. You'll figure that out eventually. You do not pass the same address to different threads, and if you do that - you shouldn't expect different threads to see different values at that address.

Comment: hw.c(59) : warning C4022: 'CreateThread' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 4

Comment: @user1766777 does the word "casting" mean anything to you?

Comment: so what you are saying is that i should cast the int to LPVOID then cast it back to int in the thread?

Comment: hmmmmm the program crashed right away.... maybe i did the casting wrong. how would you recommend doing it

Comment: @user1766777 did you adjust the thread function accordingly? Your original implementation treats it as pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
&i
```

to this:

```
(void*)i
```

And this:

```
int count = *(int*)Param + 1
```

to this:

```
int count = ((int)Param) + 1;
```